# Slideshow with Css/html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm on my way to making a website for the place I work at. I want to implement a slideshow, although it's working and easy to add pictures, I gotta think about the others who don't know coding. Is there a way for the slideshow to take all the pictures from a folder instead of putting one picture at a time? I am willing to use javascript if needed.
Note: the pictures has been changed to protect the people I work with.

```css
div#slider {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden
}
div#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: left;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite;
}
div#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div id="slider">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EhbdZyQ.png" alt="mali">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/135XMJI.png" alt="mali">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ahjHkRJ.png" alt="mali">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EhbdZyQ.png" alt="mali">

    </figure>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Client side javascript has no access to the server filesystem for security purposes.  Is this site built on Node.JS by any chance?  It would be helpful to know what the server language you are using is.

Comment: If you want to know how many files in your server in particular directory is, you will need PHP and JavaScript to create as many `img` tags.

Comment: at the moment, I have no knowledge on what the server language I will be using. I'd have to check it out when the time comes to upload everything.

Comment: @Dan not knowing the production environment is a very difficult place to start developing from.  If all you are required to do is upload a final product when it's done, I'd venture to guess that the expectation is a static HTML site with no backend code at all.  I would suggest just hardcoding the slider with the images.  Then if they need to change them ever, they will have to update the markup with the appropriate urls after upload the images.  They'd also have to update the CSS or make sure the slide count stays the same.  It would probably be best for them to have you do it when needed.

Comment: Oh alright, Thanks. Yeah, when it's done all I have to do is to upload the final product.

Comment: you may want to look at existing slide presentation solutions using html/js/css such as reveal.js ( http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/ )